# Is there locktime but in the other way around? (valid until block x)

Tags: locktime

Locktime defines the earliest block number that the transaction can be added to the blockchain. Is there any way to define the latest block number that a transaction can be mined? For example, transaction cannot be mined with block height > 840000.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin does not yet have such a built-in capability. However, such things can actually be regulated indirectly through fee (although this is a rather "rough" approach based on fee estimation).

A lower fee will cause the transaction to be mined later, while a higher fee will cause it to be mined earlier. However, as I said, this is a rather rough approach, because nothing guarantees you that the transaction will actually be mined at the moment (block) you estimated, in the end it's all up to the miner.